# I'd like to create a many-to-many table using unique values from multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure if I got the term right, but I have lists of unique values and I want to replicate each values from a lists to correspond to every value from the rest of the lists.

From the following column consisting of unique values.....

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 |
| a3 |  |  |  |

I want to create a table like this.

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| a1 | b1 | c1 | d2 |
| a1 | b1 | c2 | d1 |
| a1 | b1 | c2 | d2 |
| a1 | b2 | c1 | d1 |
| a1 | b2 | c1 | d2 |
| a1 | b2 | c2 | d1 |
| a1 | b2 | c2 | d2 |
| a2 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| a2 | b1 | c1 | d2 |
| a2 | b1 | c2 | d1 |
| a2 | b1 | c2 | d2 |
| a2 | b2 | c1 | d1 |
| a2 | b2 | c1 | d2 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | d1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 |
| a3 | b1 | c1 | d1 |
| a3 | b1 | c1 | d2 |
| a3 | b1 | c2 | d1 |
| a3 | b1 | c2 | d2 |
| a3 | b2 | c1 | d1 |
| a3 | b2 | c1 | d2 |
| a3 | b2 | c2 | d1 |
| a3 | b2 | c2 | d2 |

Is there a way to do this in excel, with the use of base functions, without manually replicating each value using copy/paste?

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365 we can use:

```
=LET(
 rng,A1:D3,
 arr,INDEX(rng,MID(BASE(SEQUENCE(ROWS(rng)^4,,0),ROWS(rng),4),SEQUENCE(,4),1)+1,{1,2,3,4}),
 FILTER(arr,(INDEX(arr,0,1)<>0)*(INDEX(arr,0,2)<>0)*(INDEX(arr,0,3)<>0)*(INDEX(arr,0,4)<>0))
 )
```

[image]

We can also change the formula a bit to not assume 4 columns:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:D3,
    clm,COLUMNS(rng),
    sclm,SEQUENCE(,clm),
    rw,ROWS(rng),
    arr,INDEX(rng,MID(BASE(SEQUENCE(rw^clm,,0),rw,clm),sclm,1)+1,sclm),
    FILTER(arr,BYROW(arr,LAMBDA(a,COUNT(--a)=0))))
```

This will do any number of columns (within reason).

[image]

Comment: Hi @Scott Craner,

Thanks for the solution. The first one worked. But the second one is more appropriate on my actual use case. However, the formula you've sent is somehow different with the attached image. Can you check?

Nevertheless, this is the first instance that I've became aware that we can use Let in excel.

Comment: You are probably getting the #NAME error.  You probably do not have BYROW() yet.

Comment: The only difference between the picture and the formula is that I removed an unneeded variable, srw.

Comment: One thing. Make sure to only choose the range of values. If you have extra columns without data it will error.

Comment: Does your formula has a limit on number of rows and columns? Because my reference table has 10-ish columns with rows ranging from 4 to 20 rows, all unique values. If I use more than 4 columns, it gives me an #VALUE! error, while for rows, if it exceeds 10 rows, it also shows #VALUE! on the rest of the row. Here's the [test dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jv9tesI4_78lyFAaicT2TMhN-2qO8c8pZm0ZRWGEgG8/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Yes, `rw^clm` would get quite big with each column added.  If you have 20 row with 4 columns you would have over a billion combinations.  Excel only has ~1.04 million rows.

Comment: Even your test data would be over 4 million.  I think Excel is not the proper tool for this.